# How to change cache-control from private to public in response header for .png file

Tags: html, image, jsp, cache-control

I have a jsp which has a .png file attached. But when the .png returned with localhost:8080/img/buttonPup.png , the cache-control is returned as private. I need to change it to public so that it can be cached by a third party(i.e AKAMAI)

```
<img src="img/buttonPup.png" onmouseover="src='img/buttonPdown.png'" 
onmouseout="src='img/buttonPup.png'"
name="bMaf${filterCounter}"
title="Make the box bigger." 
style="float:right;" onclick="moreOption('af${filterCounter}',${count})" />
```